# Vectorizing (array access and building occurence tables) in R

Tags: r, vectorization

This is my original problem, and i cannot find a good solution

lets say I have a big vector which contains a factor variable with K classes
for example, (in practice a much much bigger vector)
`vec=c("A","B","A","D","E","C","A","B")`  . (here K =5, in practice much more classes)

I define the 2 row vectors and an array

```
t=c(1,1,3,5,2)
u=c(2,7,6,1,4)
A=rbind(t,u)
```

A , t,u represents arrays/vectors of indexes

(In practice much much bigger than that, perhaps millions)

so, A has N (=2 in this example) rows, and each row is an observation

what i would like to have as an output is an array/dataframe 
with N rows, and K columns, with the number of occurences of each class in the vector generated by the indexes of each row

Hence, the first row corresponds to a vector A A A E B
the first row of my new array should be 3 1 0 0 1 representing the occurences of A,B,C,D,E

---

so i tried to decompose the problem

```
myfunction1 <- function(v) {vec[v]}
myfunction2 <- function(v) {table(vec[v])}
```

can both be vectorized

for example,

```
> myfunction1(t)
[1] "A" "A" "A" "E" "B"
```

this is ok

but, here a first problem:

```
> myfunction2(t) works, but skips C D which have no occurence

A B E 
3 1 1
```

then if i try

```
> myfunction1(A)
 [1] "A" "B" "A" "A" "A" "C" "E" "A" "B" "D"
> myfunction2(A)

A B C D E 
5 2 1 1 1
```

i get the result for the whole array considered as one single vector... not what i want !!!

If i go the mapply/sapply/lapply route,
it isn't straightforward

basically, i would need a function which from an array creates a vector of lists / lists of lists of all elements in each row and do apply on that.
which is that function i cannot find it ?

Then i sense, a problem to convert back to the right format

Lastly, i should have mentioned first,

```
> vec[A]
 [1] "A" "B" "A" "A" "A" "C" "E" "A" "B" "D"
```

returns a flat vector only

Thank you for your help !!!

I don't understand why such a simple task seems so difficult to do in R
maybe's theres an inbuilt function to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make vec a factor. If vec is a factor, then the `table` function will count all levels of the factor. Here is one method:

```
# make vec a factor
vec.f=factor(c("A","B","A","D","E","C","A","B"))

t(apply(A, 1, function(i) table(vec.f[i])))
```

This applies the lookup table method `vec.f[i]` to each row and uses `table` to tabulate the results. I transposed the result with `t` to get the desired shape. As an added benefit, `table` and `apply` remember the names of the results and apply these to the column and row names.

A vectorized and perhaps more straightforward solution, as suggested by @alexis_laz, would to use a single `table` function:

```
table(row(A), vec.f[A])
```

Here, you lose the row names as well as the order of the rows (`table` will sort row and column names alphabetically) but this is easily remedied since you can pass the sorted row names of the original matrix to the row names of the table.

Comment: thanks very much, and i knew sapply/lapply but thats the first time i see how apply is useful !!! thanks very much !!!! i was stuck on that for a long time today

Comment: @FaguiCurtain `apply` is not the fastest, colMeans and friends are much faster for their specific tasks, but `apply` can often be part of a flexible solution to matrix processing.

Comment: Similarly, after specifying the "factor", `table(row(A), vec.f[A])`

Comment: Thanks, @alexis_laz. I'll add that solution to my answer.

Comment: not sure why but table(row(A), vec.f[A]) seems to be slower. i am running 250,000 rows , 1000 indexes per row, and 40 classes. It took 46 sec with the first approach, but it took 225 sec for the vectorized solution